# javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException when using EL conditional operator in value of UIInput

Tags: jsf, input, el, placeholder, conditional-operator

I get this error message:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /u/editProfile.xhtml @64,140 value="#{empty userProfile.cfg.gpu or userProfile.cfg.gpu == '' ? usernavmsg.EditMe: userProfile.cfg.gpu}": null
```

The problem is that when the value of a bean property is null the value of an inputText field switches from my ManagedBean property, to a resource string. So I cannot persist that value.

I request the profile of the user from my database in my managed bean. If a property of the said profile is null,  the [inplace text holder](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inplace.xhtml)  value is "Edit Me". If it's not null it's the value of that property. Which is working ! However when I submit the form and try to persist a new value or no value at all the error appears. The error only appears for the field that are null to begin with (when I requested them from the db). So the problem is that when the value is null it switch from my ManagedBean property, to a resource string.

I just have a form with this:

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{usernavmsg.GPU}: "/>
        <p:inplace styleClass="lessDark">
            <p:inputText value="#{empty userProfile.cfg.gpu ? usernavmsg.EditMe: userProfile.cfg.gpu}" />
        </p:inplace>
```

when I submit the form I want to persist userProfile.cfg in the database which doesn't happen.

Can I work around this ? Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional statements in EL are indeed not writable. They are read-only. End of story. The same applies to method references in EL as in `#{bean.property()}`. It must really be a true value expression as in `#{bean.property}`.

Your approach of using a (HTML5) "placeholder" is actually wrong. For that you should be using the `placeholder` attribute, not the `value` attribute. In older versions of PrimeFaces that do not have a `placeholder` attribute you'll need passthrough.

```html
<html ... xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
...
<p:inputText value="#{userProfile.cfg.gpu}" a:placeholder="#{usernavmsg.EditMe}" ... />
```

Nowadays PrimeFaces offers a `placeholder` attribute.

```html
<p:inputText value="#{userProfile.cfg.gpu}" placeholder="#{usernavmsg.EditMe}" ... />
```

Comment: Thanks. The part about the place holder was not what I intended to do. To resolve my problem I'll put a default value of "edit me" for each field in my database. I didn't test it since I just woke up but I believe it works. I'll edit this if it doesn't.

Comment: You're welcome. As to your workaround, this is honestly really awkward. It'd better be for hobby/educational purposes. If I were the lead developer in your company, I'd almost have fired you ;) In the future questions, try elaborating the intent (the functional requirement) too. This will usually generate much better answers. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377

Comment: Markup doesn't belong in DB. Only data belongs in DB. Otherwise you're killing the portability/reusability/integrity of the DB. Moreover, unspecified data should be represented by `null`, not by an arbitrary string, even not an empty string. Not only in DB but also in programming languages.